java -jar x.jar in Windows PowerShell, non-ASCII characters cannot be displayed well
PS D:\> cd "D:\IdeaProjects\demos"
PS D:\IdeaProjects\demos> ls


    目录: D:\IdeaProjects\demos


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----         2024/9/29     13:24                .idea
d-----         2024/9/29     13:21                src
d-----         2024/9/29     13:24                target
-a----         2024/9/29     13:12           2461 .gitignore
-a----         2024/9/29     13:23           2591 pom.xml
-a----         2024/9/29     13:25              0 Simplified Chinese 简体中文.txt


PS D:\IdeaProjects\demos> java -jar D:\IdeaProjects\demos\target\grabled-chars-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
SLF4J(I): Connected with provider of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider]
13:25:49.259 [main] INFO Application -- Simplified Chinese 绠€浣撲腑鏂?

PS D:\IdeaProjects\demos>

From the result of ls ,we can see Simplified Chinese 简体中文.txt is displayed well.
And here is the source code of grabled-chars-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar. It is very simple,
@Slf4j
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        log.info("Simplified Chinese 简体中文");
    }
}

with Lombok and logback-classic:1.5.8.
But the output in PowerShell is 13:25:49.259 [main] INFO Application -- Simplified Chinese 绠€浣撲腑鏂?
How can I fix this?

Try: $OutputEncoding = [console]::InputEncoding = [console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding, see: Using UTF-8 Encoding (CHCP 65001) in Command Prompt / Windows Powershell (Windows 10)

(1) Power Shell run command chcp , show current codepage (2) 3 possible setting , 936(GBK) , 437 , 65001 (UTF-8) (3) `PS C:\Users\User\demos-garbled-chars\target> chcp
活动代码页: 936
PS C:\Users\User\demos-garbled-chars\target> java -jar grabled-chars-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
SLF4J(I): Connected with provider of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider]
04:38:54.128 [main] INFO Application -- Simplified Chinese 简体中文`

(4) `PS C:\Users\User\demos-garbled-chars\target> chcp
Active code page: 437
PS C:\Users\User\demos-garbled-chars\target> java -jar grabled-chars-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
SLF4J(I): Connected with provider of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider]
05:00:32.281 [main] INFO Application -- Simplified Chinese ????(But in en_US, code page 437, Power Shell shows??????` , which I think is correct.)

Hi @iRon Many thanks for your help, after executing $OutputEncoding = [console]::InputEncoding = [console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding in powershell, now output of jar -jar is displayed well!

Hi @life888888 Many thanks your advice, but we followed advice from iRon first and it works, so I cannot verify if your solution can help. And would you mind wrting it as a formal answer? currently it is a bit unfriendly to read.

Finally, I tested the same situation (codepage 936 GBK + JDK 21). The simplest solution: remove JDK 21 and install JDK 17. (The reason is that after JDK 18+, the default encoding has been adjusted)

Base on your source code (https://github.com/XSun771/demos/tree/garbled-chars)

Windows codepage 936 (GBK) + JDK 21 will get the same error message (Simplified Chinese 绠€浣撲腑鏂?).
Windows codepage 936 (GBK) + JDK 17 will get the correct message.

Solution 1 - Remove JDK 21 and install JDK 17
Solution 2 - Add logback.xml config file
Project Tree
demos-garbled-chars
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   └── main
│       ├── java
│       │   └── Application.java
│       └── resources
│           └── logback.xml
...

Add logback.xml to your project

ADD <charset>GBK</charset> to ConsoleAppender - encoder
ADD <charset>UTF-8</charset> to RollingFileAppender - encoder

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="Console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %-50logger{40} - %msg%n</pattern>
            <charset>GBK</charset>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
     
    <appender name="RollingFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>app.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %-50logger{40} - %msg%n</pattern>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        </encoder>
         
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>1MB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>10MB</totalSizeCap>
            <cleanHistoryOnStart>true</cleanHistoryOnStart>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
     
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    </root>
</configuration>

build & run
build
mvn clean package

run
java -jar grabled-chars-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Powershell Will show Correct output message.
and log file app.log use UTF-8 , log the correct output message.
Solution 3: Use JVM parameters to adjust encoding. (Not tested)
You can choose Solution 1 or Solution 2 as your solution.
